# How to organize this setup with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, schema, database, nosql

I'm coming from a strictly MySQL background and MongoDB is my first contact with NoSQL. Let's say I have a bunch of users and a bunch of groups.

The user schema:

```
user_id
username
email
```

The group schema

```
group_id
name
description
```

If I was using MySQL and I wanted to have a relationship of each user and the group they belong to, I'd create another table with `user_id -> group_id` relationships. Would it be proper to create another MongoDB collection for this relationship? If not, what should the scheme look like?

Comment: If a user's group holds the same value as a group's group_id, aren't they then related?

Comment: @CoreyOgburn, yeah my bad, that was a typo.

Comment: I think that was your answer. If you really want to bind a user to a group properly, use a [Database Reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#dbrefs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you take a look at the [data modeling documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/) available on the MondoDB site. The answer to your question will differ depending on the nature of the relationship between a user and a group. You may want to use references or you could store the group info inside the user document.

It could look something like this if you embed it in the user document:

```
{
   user_id: "the id",
   username: "Something",
   email: "something@something.com",
   group: {
             name: "some name",
             description: "some description"
          }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

no schema in mongo...  the User's group field would either hold an actual group object, or a reference like the group's id.

see [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/) mongo doc.